# Porque as propriedades do CSS mudam nos navegadores

Tags: css

Por que dependendo do navegador existe a necessidade de usar propriedades diferentes?
Por exemplo:

**FIREFOX**

```
-moz-column-width:150px;
```

**OUTRO**

```
-webkit-column-width:150px;
```

Existem muitos outros casos, mas, o que quero saber é por que não é simplesmente "column-width" e se os outros navegadores não entendem todos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você está apontando é chamado de *[vendor prefix](http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/vendor-prefixes/)*.

De maneira sucinta, isso acontece porque o processo de adição de uma nova especificação ocorre de maneira independente entre implementações. O processo geralmente ocorre da seguinte maneira:

- O [W3C (World Wide Web Consortium)](http://www.w3.org/) cria uma especificação.
- Diferentes vendors (Mozilla, WebKit, etc) iniciam a implementação; durante este período são utilizados os vendor prefixes, de maneira a ajudar a identificação de diferentes comportamentos;
- O padrão é finalizado, o formato final é estabelecido, e vendor prefixes relativos utilizados durante a implementação são declarados obsoletos (em inglês [`deprecated`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)).

Um exemplo prático:

- `border-radius` é [discutido e sugerido](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-background-20120724/) em 2012.
- `-webkit-border-radius` é implementado para Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2 e Android 1.6;
- `-moz-border-radius` é implementado e utilizado no Firefox 1-3.6;
- Depois de um período de amadurecimento, `border-radius` é considerado estabelecido e disponível para Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4 e Android 2.1+.

O problema é que você não é prático reimplementar todo código que possui uma menção às versões com vendor prefix - então eles são mantidos por questões de compatibilidade. Com isso, é mantida uma 'tabela' interna de resolução que redireciona menções *vendor-specific* para suas versões finais.

Para evitar o efeito de bloating, empresas como a Google [planejam monitorar o uso de certas tags CSS](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Deprecating%20features%20and%20vendor%20prefixes) e prever o impacto da remoção do conteúdo obsoleto.

Comment: Mas a tendência é que com o tempo eles caiam em desuso, sejam depreciados e por fim descontinuados.

Answer (score 3):

Isso iniciou quando essas propriedade começaram a ser desenvolvidas, dessa forma o [w3c](/questions/tagged/w3c) ainda não havia feito as definições sobre as propriedades.

Então os produtores de cada navegador passou a usar nomes que relacionassem as propriedades aos seus navegadores como um forma de não conflitar a interpretação dessa propriedade com outros navegadores eles fora chamados de [vendor prefix](http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/vendor-prefixes/).

Hoje você pode ver que existem várias propriedades que além de ter o `-moz-` ou `-webkit-` também são escritas sem, como o `border-radius` por exemplo, isso quer dizer que a [w3c](/questions/tagged/w3c) já padronizou a propriedade, dessa forma todos os browser "tem" que entender tanto a sua nomenclatura quanto a  nomenclatura da [w3c](/questions/tagged/w3c).

Answer (score 2):

É porque essas são propriedades usadas durante o aperfeiçoamento do código do navegador, de forma que, uma vez que tudo esteja perfeito, sejam usados os nomes recomendados pelos padrões.

Isso quer dizer que em um dado ponto, o navegador passa a aceitar o nome indicado pelo padrão.

Note que não existe nenhuma garantia de que os nomes particulares de cada marca, sirva para o propósito que o nome padronizado propões.